# Ubuntu pjsip python compilation

Tags: python, pjsip

Following instructions for compiling python and PjSIP
http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Build_Install
When doing last step:
make

I get

```
/home/<user>/Downloads/pjproject-2.1.0/pjsip/lib/libpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I tried recompile with:
./configure CFLAGS='-fPIC'

or use user.make

```
export CFLAGS += -O2 -fPIC
#export LDFLAGS +=
```

But same issue

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Answer (score 0):

After a make clean, all worked fine.